# Convert Mvc Core view to pdf with Rotativa

Tags: pdf, asp.net-core-mvc, rotativa

I am working on mvc core application, there i needs to convert a view into pdf.
For that i find `Rotativa.NetCore` in `NugGet Pakages`.

[image]

But it does not work.

```
public class TestViewModel
    {
        public int DocId { get; set; }
        public string DocContent { get; set; }
    }

public class RotativaController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = string.Format("Hello to ASP.NET MVC Core!");
            return View();
        }

        //Convert Index View To PDF
        public ActionResult PrintIndex()
        {
            return new ActionAsPdf("Index");
        } //Not working.

        //Convert TestViewModel Model To PDF
        public ActionResult PrintTestViewModel()
        {
            List<TestViewModel> _list = new List<TestViewModel>();
            _list.Add(new TestViewModel { DocId = 1, DocContent = "Content 1" });
            _list.Add(new TestViewModel { DocId = 2, DocContent = "Content 2" });
            _list.Add(new TestViewModel { DocId = 3, DocContent = "Content 3" });
            _list.Add(new TestViewModel { DocId = 4, DocContent = "Content 4" });
            _list.Add(new TestViewModel { DocId = 5, DocContent = "Content 5" });
            return new ViewAsPdf(_list);
        } //Not working.
    }
```

Through exception as

```
TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.CookieAuthenticationOptions' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
```

Comment: any update of this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple.

At this time the current branch is on .NetCoreApp 1.0.

There is a pull request waiting to update the .netcore to 2.0.

A simple workaround is to download the solution, un load the project and update the following lines:

```
<TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFrameworks> 

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

After that, reload the project, resolve the issue with **CookieAuthenticationOptions** and that is it.

Answer (score 0):

The CookieAuthenticationOptions class only applies to NetCore 1.x not NetCore 2.0.

To get Rotativa.NetCore to work on NetCore 2.0 you need to download the Rotativa.NetCore source code from GitHub: https://github.com/aaxelm/Rotativa.NetCore, make the changes outlined here: https://github.com/aaxelm/Rotativa.NetCore/pull/1/files?diff=split and then add this project as an Existing Project to your Solution in Visual Studio.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use [AllowAnonymous] on the action "Index".
Otherwise set FormsAuthenticationCookieName and Cookies property in ActionAsPdf.